# Pass array value as input

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a function that returns a list of IP addresses.

I call the function from my test script `dns.pl` and use a `for` loop to pass one address at a time as input to a command.

I want to pass all but one IP address as input (all at once) to a command in the script.

I want to check if the address matches = x.x.x.x. If so then skip that address and pass the other addresses as input to the below command in the script.

```
# The IP address that are retuned by the function should be passed here as input all at once. Except one ip address

./dns.pl -t ipaddress1,ip address2,.... ipadress,n  -f .5 -S C

# function call to get the list of  ip addresses

$self->{'machine_ip'} = $self->{'queryObj'}->get_machine_ip( $self->{'vip_owner'} );

# Currently, I'm passing one ip address at a time using foreach
# But, I want to  pass all but one ip address all at once  to the below command as input.

foreach my $ip ( @{ $self->{'machine_ip'} } ) {
    $self->{'exec_obj'}->execute(./dns.pl -t ipaddress1,ip address2,.... ipadress,n  -f .5 -S C);
}

sub get_machine_ip {

    my ( $self, $vip_owner ) = @_;
    my @ip        = ();
    my $sql_query = $self->{queryObj}->execute("select machineIP from sripd_peer_Status where frontend=$vip_owner");
    my $records   = $self->{queryObj}->result();

    foreach my $row ( @$records ) {
        push @ip, $row->{machineIP};
    }

    return \@ip;
}
```

Comment: You do realise that `//` doesn't work for comments in `perl` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to remove the unwanted IP address from the array.

```
$self->{machine_ip} = $self->{queryObj}->get_machine_ip($self->{vip_owner});

my @ips_minus_value = grep {$_ ne 'IP_ADDRESS_TO_REMOVE'} @{$self->{machine_ip}};
$self->{exec_obj}->execute("./dns.pl -t " . join(',', @ips_minus_value) . " -f .5 -S C");
```

Comment: I wanted to remove two elements from the array. I tried the below. But it didn't work.  my @array = grep {$_ !~  ((m/@{$self->{'service_ip_of_machine1'}}/)
      && (m/@{$self->{'service_ip_of_machine2}}/)) } @{$self->{'machine_ip'}};